# Synchronizing access to a MDB method across instances

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, synchronization, message-driven-bean

I have an Message Driven Bean, which receives Audit messages. These messages also have information about the system being audited. When a message is received, the MDB can create the system if it does not exists or reuse an existing system.

My challenge is that when a lot of messages from a new system are received simultaneously, multiple MDB instances are created and can end up creating duplicate systems. Adding a constraint to the database is one way to solve it. Is there a way of avoiding these duplicates in the application, MDB in this case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
private Object LOCK;
public void onMessage() {
    code…
    synchronized(LOCK) {
        check if system exists, create if necessary
    }
    more code…
}
```

Comment: this code will synchronize on a single instance only, making LOCK static will synchronize on all class instances, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have only a single Thread processing all the Messages. This can be configured on the Activation Spec, connection Pool.

Answer (score 2):

`MessageDrivenBean` can be synchronized via queue [Destination Options](http://activemq.apache.org/destination-options.html). In my case `MessageDriven` annotation looks like this for single message processing:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "ArchiveCounterStJmsListener", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = LINK_TO_QUEUE + "?consumer.dispatchAsync=false&consumer.prefetchSize=1"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSessions", propertyValue = "1")
})
```